# Ionic : How to access a variable in another service factory?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, controller, native, factory

I'm quite new to Ionic and I was just wondering if it was possible to access another array variable in another service factory ?

Basically, I have 2 service factories which import data such as jobs and jobs that are saved by the user.

I want to be able to push data from the jobs service factory into the saved service factory. I was thinking of using global array variables but I'm not sure if that's going to work.

Here's the code:

Services.js:

```js
.factory('Jobs', function() {
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array

  // Some fake testing data
  var jobs = [{
    id: 0,
    title: 'Maintenance Engineer',
    category: 'Permanent',
    salary: '£24,000',
    hoursWeek: '39.02',
    location: 'Long Eaton',
    type: 'Engineering',
    logo: './img/job-icon.png',
    description: ''
  }, {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Internal Sales Executive',
    category: 'Permanent',
    salary: '£25,000',
    hoursWeek: '39.02',
    location: 'Erdington',
    type: 'Engineering',
    logo: './img/job-icon.png',
    description: ''
  },{
    id: 2,
    title: 'Production Supervisor',
    category: 'Permanent',
    salary: '£24,000',
    hoursWeek: '39.02',
    location: 'Rotherham',
    type: 'Engineering',
    logo: './img/job-icon.png',
    description: ''
  }, {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Warehouse Operative',
    category: 'Temporary',
    salary: '£24,000',
    hoursWeek: '39.02',
    location: 'Markham Vale, Chesterfield',
    type: 'Engineering',
    logo: './img/job-icon.png',
    description: ''
  }, {
    id: 4,
    title: 'Delivery Driver',
    category: 'Permanent',
    salary: '£24,000',
    hoursWeek: '39.02',
    location: 'Mansfield',
    type: 'Logistics',
    logo: 'https://dttdeliveries.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Corporate-Logo-Plain.png',
    description: ''
  }];

  return {
    all: function() {
      return jobs;
    },
    save: function(jobs) {
      saved.push(jobs.indexOf(jobs), 1);
      console.log(saved);
    },
    get: function(jobsId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
        if (jobs[i].id === parseInt(jobsId)) {
          return jobs[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
})

.factory('Saved', function() {

  var saved = [{
    id: 3,
    title: 'Warehouse Operative',
    category: 'Temporary',
    salary: '£24,000',
    hoursWeek: '39.02',
    location: 'Markham Vale, Chesterfield',
    type: 'Engineering',
    logo: './img/job-icon.png',
    description: ''
  }, {
    id: 4,
    title: 'Delivery Driver',
    category: 'Permanent',
    salary: '£24,000',
    hoursWeek: '39.02',
    location: 'Mansfield',
    type: 'Logistics',
    logo: 'https://dttdeliveries.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Corporate-Logo-Plain.png',
    description: ''
  }];

  return {
    all: function() {
      return saved;
    },
    remove: function(saved) {
      saved.splice(saved.indexOf(saved), 1);
      console.log(saved);
    },
    get: function(savedId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < saved.length; i++) {
        if (saved[i].id === parseInt(savedId)) {
          return saved[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
})
```

Controller.js:

```js
.controller('JobsCtrl', function($scope, Jobs) {
  $scope.jobs = Jobs.all();
  $scope.save = function(job) {
    Jobs.save(job);
  }
})

.controller('SavedCtrl', function($scope, Saved) {
  $scope.saved = Saved.all();
  $scope.remove = function(save) {
    Saved.remove(save);
  }
})
```

As you can see from the code,

```
  save: function(jobs) {
  saved.push(jobs.indexOf(jobs), 1);
  console.log(saved);
}
```

I'm trying to push a job into the saved job array but I'm getting `the saved is not defined` error which is understandable as the array variables are in separate factories. I'm just not sure what's the best way to go about this.

Would appreciate any information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to refactor your factory as below. You can see that, in the factory, we are returning the scope, $self, which makes it easier to access the factory object.

**Factory.js**

```
.factory('Saved', function() {
    var $self = this;

    $self.saved = [{
      id: 3,
      title: 'Warehouse Operative'
    }];

    $self.remove = function(saved) {
      $self.saved.splice(saved.indexOf(saved), 1);
      console.log($self.saved);
    };

    return $self;
  })
```

**Controller.js**

```
 .controller('SavedCtrl', function($scope, Saved) {
    $scope.saved = Saved.saved;

    $scope.remove = function(save) {
      Saved.remove(save);
    };

    $scope.add = function(save) {
      Saved.saved.push(save);
      console.log(Saved.saved);
    };
  })
```